# When trying to read from a text file in c++ it gives me a large random number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a program that gets your name and greets you with it. Here is my code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


       ifstream infile;
       infile.open("Info.txt");

int x;

infile >> x;

cout << "Hello " << x << endl;



return 0;
}
```

My Info.txt only contains 1 line that just says "Bob", but when I run the program all I get is "Hello 1978627034"

Comment: Why do you (try to) read an `int`? `Bob` is not an `int`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you try to read `"Bob"` into an `int`?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: You assumed `infile >> x` *worked*; it *didn't*, but you don't know that because you never checked. Assumption is the mother of all... If you *check* your IO operations for success, `if (infile >> x)` you'll see that statement *failed*, and in so doing, left `x` with an indeterminate value you posthumously report to stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read in the name as a string, not an int:

```
ifstream infile;
infile.open("Info.txt");

string x;

infile >> x;

cout << "Hello" << x << endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Bob is not an int,
change it to string.